# Aligns with phone image on the right of the bootstrap div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need to align the phone with the icon of each other 's side of the bootstrap , and is giving an error , wish someone help me up.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="container">

<address class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="imagens/telefone.png" class="img-responsive pull-right" />
        <div class="pull-right">(85) 8743.1561</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="imagens/telefone.png" class="img-responsive pull-left" />(85) 8743.1561
    </div>

</address>

</footer>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where do you want to align it, and what exactly are you planning to accomplish?

Comment: I want to align an icon next to the text and then all centered in the middle of the page

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you are doing this on your footer, but for the "centered in the middle of the page" part, you want something like this:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="container">

    <address class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3">
            <img src="imagens/telefone.png" class="img-responsive pull-right" />
        <div class="col-sm-2">(85) 8743.1561</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="imagens/telefone.png" class="img-responsive pull-left" />
        </div>
     </address>
</footer>
```

You can of course change the value of the `col-sm-offset` and of the `col-sm` to whatever you need. If I'm missing something, please let me know, and I'll try and improve my answer.